# Цикл замены пропущенных значений после нахождения первого вхождения не пропущенного значения

Tags: r

Есть `dataframe f` с наименованиями товара, часть первых 10-ти значений пропущены, только потом начинается значения одного товара.

```
Item
NA  
NA  
Phone  
Phone  
Phone  
NA  
NA
```

Необходимо найти первое вхождение не пропущенного значения и после него все строки до конца заполнить этим значением.

Пробовал сделать приведенным ниже циклом, результат не достигнут.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(f)) {buffer_Item <- f[i, "Item"];  if (is.na(buffer_Item)==FALSE) {a <- i+1} else {break};  for (a in a:nrow(f))  {f[a, "Item"]<-"Phone"}  }
```

Необходимо чтобы получилось:

```
Item
NA  
NA  
Phone  
Phone  
Phone  
Phone
```

Comment: Посмотрите `zoo::na.locf`.

Answer (score 0):

Имеем `data.csv` следующего содержания:

```
Item
NA
NA
Phone
Phone
Phone
NA
NA
Phone
Phone
NA
NA
Phone
Phone
```

Вариант 1: с использованием цикла

```
fl <- "data.csv"
df <- read.csv(fl, header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# определили временную переменную, которая в дальнейшем будет равна первому значению дата фрэйма != NA
frst = NA

# запускаем цикл
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  #находим значение временной переменной = первому значению не NA
  #из условия, что Временная переменная еще равна NA и текущее значение Item уже не равно NA
  if (is.na(frst) == TRUE & is.na(df[i, ]) == FALSE) frst <- df[i, ]

  #начинаем присваивать значение frst для значений, которые = NA      
  if (is.na(frst) == FALSE & is.na(df[i, ]) == TRUE) df[i, ] <- frst
}
```

Вариант 2: без использования цикла, с использованием возможностей dplyr, для наглядности и удобства анализа не используются один и тот же дата фрэйм 
Вариант 2 более наглядный

```
fl <- "data.csv"
library(dplyr)

df2 <- read.csv(fl, header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# создали дополнительный столбец, который равен значению номер строки
df2.1 <- mutate(df2, nr = as.integer(row(df2)))
```

Получили результат

```
Item nr
<NA>  1
<NA>  2
Phone  3
Phone  4
Phone  5
<NA>  6
<NA>  7
Phone  8
Phone  9
<NA> 10
<NA> 11
Phone 12
Phone 13


# исключили все строки с NA и таким образом самая первая запись будет так, которую потребуется разтиражировать
df2.2 <- na.omit(df2.1)
```

Промежуточный вариант:

```
 Item nr
Phone  3
Phone  4
Phone  5
Phone  8
Phone  9
Phone 12
Phone 13
```

Присваиваем значения временным переменным для использования в дальнейших условиях

```
frst <- df2.2[1, 1]
rw <- df2.2[1, 2]
```

Создаем столбец Item2 (для наглядности) с помощью `mutate` значений `Item == NA` и строки больше `rw`

```
df2.3 <- mutate(df2.1, Item2 = ifelse(nr > rw & is.na(Item)==TRUE, frst, Item))
```